# every positive rational number can be written as a finite sum of distinct numbers of the form 1/n where n is natural

Tags: irrational-numbers

> every positive rational number can be written as a finite sum of distinct numbers of the form 1/n where n is natural

I don't quite understand this question. Actually, what does *distinct numbers of the form $1/n$* mean? Does it mean $m(1/n)$ or $(1/n)^m$? Can anyone express $17/15$ as an example?

Comment: it means: $\forall q \in \mathbb{Q}$ there exists $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ such that $q = \sum_{n \in A} \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Related link: [Egyptian fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction)

Comment: For example: $2/3 = 1/2 + 1/6$. And $17/15 = 1/1 + 1/10 + 1/30$.

Comment: @ Mees de Vries Is there any formula to get the result?

Comment: I came up with that example by (basically) trial and error. There are algorithms and proofs of existence on the linked Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, "distinct numbers of the form $\frac{1}{n}$" refers to numbers like $\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{1}{3}$, $\frac{1}{4}$, etc.  There is no "m" as numerator or exponent.  The "distinct" means that all the denominators are different.